# jQuery for each 24 over a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, foreach

I have this code

```
if ($('input#grommet').is(':checked')) {
     if (width <= 96) {
           var grommetQTY = 4;
     } else if (width > 96) {
            grommetQTY = (Math.floor(width / 24));
            grommetQTY = grommetQTY - 4;
            grommetQTY = grommetQTY * 2;
            grommetQTY = grommetQTY +4;
     }
}
```

and I need to add 2 to the grommetQTY for each whole 24 inches (2 feet) over 96 width. Is there a way to do this?
What this is attempting to accomplish is giving the pricing for a banner. We add 2 more grommets at 2 feet intervals, but because this is custom sizing, it could be 96 feet wide, and I don't want to have to write an else if statement for each two foot interval. I am hoping there is a way to only add two to the quantity everytime the width goes another 24 inches over the standard 96 inch width so if width is 96 or less, qty is 4, at 120 its 6, at 144 its 8, etc

Comment: Could you just do `grommetQTY = Math.floor(96/24) * 2` ?

Comment: So learn about the Modulus

Comment: I am lost - 12?, 24? 2, 96, so many numbers. Could you try to explain what exactly you want to receive?

Comment: edited for clarification, and title edited to be 24

Comment: Please create a [mininimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You got most of it, but it's hard to understand the problem in its current state.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than coming up with the equation for this, here is a for loop that will do what you need:

```
var grommetQTY = 0;
for(var i = 96; i < n; i++)
    if(i%24 == 0) 
        grommetQTY += 2;
```

where n is the length. This is terrible inefficient and could be sped up by just doing:

```
var grommetQTY = 0;
for(var i = 96; i < n; i+=24)
    grommetQTY += 2;
```

This is nicer but still not ideal. The ideal solution in your case would be an equation.

P.S - The equation is `Math.floor( Math.max((n - 96), 0) / 24 ) * 2 + 4` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: You are assigning in your `if` statement.

Comment: my bad. was just typing up some quick psuedo code. Fixed it

Comment: @Sharkn8do check the last line of my answer for an equation that will handle all cases.

Comment: Don't put your code here, just edit your question. Nobody can read that!

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow(2, grommetQTY) * (Math.floor(96 / 24))`

2 to the grommetQTY for each whole 24 inches in 96. Is that what you need?

`Math.pow(a, b)` gives `a` to the power of `b`

---

**Edit:**

`var qty = (Math.floor(n / 24)) * 2`

Where `n` is the pixels (96 in your example).

---

**Edit:**

```
var qty = 4 + ((width > 96) ? ((Math.floor((width - 96) / 24) * 2) : 0);
```

Is that it?

Comment: close, I need 2 added to the quantity for every 24 inches over 96. so if width is 96 or less, qty is 4, at 120 its 6, at 144 its 8, etc.

Comment: I edited it. Is that it? I suggest you learn some basic arithmetic. It's more of a math problem, rather than a JavaScript one. Or a jQuery one for that matter.

Comment: @Sharkn8do, after explaining why the answer is wrong, wait for an edit, before asking for it to be closed. *Closing an answer is for low-quality answers **not** wrong answers*. At least until it is obvious there isn't going  to be an edit fixing it.

Comment: I think he meant that my answer is _close_. Without the **d**, meaning that I _almost_ gave him the answer.

Comment: Sorry if that's what it meant. To me it sounded like "close this answer, because..."

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var extra = width - 96
var grommetQTY = 4;
if (extra > 0) {
  grommet += Math.floor((extra / 24)) * 2;
}
```

The variable `extra` holds, as the name implies, extra length that you would want to take into consideration. If it's 0 or below that means it's 96 and under.

Then, for `extra > 0` you could alternatively change it to `extra >= 24` as any extra value less than 24 will return 0.

Comment: Please add to your answer. It's not a complete answer as it is.

Comment: @David as an explanation or?

Comment: An explanation of the code would be great, likely the OP would like more explanation. This [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/348684), really explains what I mean.

Comment: @DavidArchibald Is it really necessary to provide a detailed explanation when the arithmetic should be obvious to anyone with high school math education?

Comment: Without getting into a debate *It's a matter of opinion.* I feel that in any case something can be improved **It should.**

Comment: If `extra` is 10, grommet will be `4.41`. He said _for each whole 24 inches_.

Comment: @Hristiyan Forgot javascript doesn't truncate decimals if divider is a whole number.